# What does “`str` does not have a constant size known at compile-time” mean, and what's the simplest way to fix it?

Tags: string, pointers, rust

I'm trying to manipulate a string derived from a function parameter and then return the result of that manipulation:

```
fn main() {
    let a: [u8; 3] = [0, 1, 2]; 
    for i in a.iter() {
        println!("{}", choose("abc", *i));
    }
}

fn choose(s: &str, pad: u8) -> String {
    let c = match pad {
        0 => ["000000000000000", s].join("")[s.len()..],
        1 => [s, "000000000000000"].join("")[..16],
        _ => ["00", s, "0000000000000"].join("")[..16],
    };
    c.to_string()
}
```

On building, I get this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `str: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
 --> src\main.rs:9:9
  |
9 |     let c = match pad {
  |         ^ `str` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `str`
  = note: all local variables must have a statically known size
```

What's wrong here, and what's the simplest way to fix it?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**TL;DR** Don't use `str`, use `&str`. The reference is important.

---

The issue can be simplified to this:

```
fn main() {
    let demo = "demo"[..];
}
```

You are attempting to slice a `&str` (but the same would happen for a `String`, `&[T]`, `Vec<T>`, etc.), but have not taken a reference to the result. This means that the type of `demo` would be `str`. To fix it, add an `&`:

```
let demo = &"demo"[..];
```

In your broader example, you are also running into the fact that you are creating an allocated `String` inside of the `match` statement (via `join`) and then attempting to return a reference to it. This is disallowed because the `String` will be dropped at the end of the `match`, invalidating any references. In another language, this could lead to memory unsafety.

One potential fix is to store the created `String` for the duration of the function, preventing its deallocation until after the new string is created:

```
fn choose(s: &str, pad: u8) -> String {
    let tmp;

    match pad {
        0 => {
            tmp = ["000000000000000", s].join("");
            &tmp[s.len()..]
        }
        1 => {
            tmp = [s, "000000000000000"].join("");
            &tmp[..16]
        }
        _ => {
            tmp = ["00", s, "0000000000000"].join("");
            &tmp[..16]
        }
    }.to_string()
}
```

Editorially, there's probably more efficient ways of writing this function. The [formatting machinery](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html) has options for padding strings. You might even be able to just truncate the string returned from `join` without creating a new one.

---

What it means is harder to explain succinctly. Rust has a number of types that are *unsized*. The most prevalent ones are `str` and `[T]`. Contrast these types to how you normally see them used: `&str` or `&[T]`. You might even see them as `Box<str>` or `Arc<[T]>`. The commonality is that they are always used behind a reference of some kind.

Because these types don't have a size, they cannot be stored in a variable on the stack — the compiler wouldn't know how much stack space to reserve for them! That's the essence of the error message.

See also:

- [What is the return type of the indexing operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27879161/155423)
- [Return local String as a slice (&str)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29428227/155423)
- [Why your first FizzBuzz implementation may not work](https://chrismorgan.info/blog/rust-fizzbuzz.html)

Comment: Than you. Special additional thanks for the pointer to string padding, which I'll investigate shortly. A language like Rust or Python, with it's lovely, vast, almost-built-in libraries, is a slightly two-edged sword. Still got a lot to learn...

Comment: "What it means is harder to explain succinctly." Then goes on to explain it succinctly.

Comment: @AndreKR Thanks (I think)! However, that part of the answer is pretty weak, as it doesn't really explain *how* something can be "unsized" or why such a concept is useful, not to mention glossing over what the stack is.

Comment: I think most languages store their local variables on a stack, so it's a familiar concept. And why it's unsized is in the error message - it doesn't implement `Sized`. I just didn't make the connection until I read your post.

Comment: Further explanation why we can't use str instead of &str:
https://users.rust-lang.org/t/str-size-at-compile-time/76970/2