# Unknown size at compile time when trying to print string contents in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a couple of pieces of code, once errors out and the other doesn't, and I don't understand why.

**The one that errors out when compiling:**

```
fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("hello");

    println!("{}", *s1);
}
```

This throws: doesn't have a size known at compile-time, on the line `println!("{}", *s1);`

**The one that works:**

```
fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("hello");

    print_string(&s1);

}

fn print_string(s1: &String) {
    println!("{}", *s1);
}
```

Why is this happening? Aren't both correct ways to access the string contents and printing them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does “\`str\` does not have a constant size known at compile-time” mean, and what's the simplest way to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393462/what-does-str-does-not-have-a-constant-size-known-at-compile-time-mean-and)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first snippet you’re dereferencing a `String`. This yields an `str` which is [a dynamically sized type (sometimes called unsized types in older texts)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/2018-edition/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait). DSTs are somewhat difficult to use directly

In the second snippet you’re dereferencing a `&String`, which yields a regular `String`, which is a normal sized type.

In both cases the dereference is completely useless, why are you even using one?