# Filtering files or directories discovered with fs::read_dir()

Tags: file, rust, iteration, mapping, filtering

I've got this function:

```
fn folders(dir: &Path) -> Result<Vec<PathBuf>, io::Error> {
    fs::read_dir(dir)?
        .into_iter()
        .map(|x| x.map(|entry| entry.path()))
        .collect()
}
```

It's actually borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439327/how-to-write-a-function-that-returns-vecpath). The function is OK; unfortunately, I don't really understand how it works.

```
Ok(["/home/ey/dir-src/9", "/home/ey/dir-src/11", "/home/ey/dir-src/03 A Letter of Explanation.mp3", "/home/ey/dir-src/02 Egyptian Avenue.mp3", "/home/ey/dir-src/alfa", "/home/ey/dir-src/10"])
```

The test output shows both directories and files, just as it should. I can't figure out where to put filtering for files/directories. I don't understand why the mapping inside mapping: isn't it just a simple list of paths? What is really happening inside this expression?

UPD:

```
fn folders(dir: &Path) -> Result<Vec<PathBuf>, io::Error> {
    fs::read_dir(dir)?
        .into_iter()
        .map(|x| x.map(|entry| entry.path()))
        .filter(|x| {x.as_ref().map(|entry| entry); true})
        .collect()
}
```

A trivial filter (always `true`) inserted. It is compiling at least, but I still can't see how am I supposed to use `entry` for file/directory checking. Sorry :)

Comment: The documentation in [std::iter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html) may be a good read for you, if you haven't read it yet.

Comment: What kind of filtering do you want to do?

Comment: To pass files only, or directories only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's walk step by step through the chain.

```
fs::read_dir(dir)?
```

creates a read handle to the directory, immediately propagates the `Err` case if it happens, and if it does not, `unwrap`s the success (that's the `?` operator)

```
.into_iter()
```

turns this read handle into an iterator of `Result<DirEntry>`

```
.map(|x|
  x.map(|entry| entry.path())
)
```

This calls the `path()` method on every element of the iterator if the result is an actual `DirEntry`. Because the iterator element is `Result<DirEntry>` and not just `DirEntry`, the second `map()` allows you to deal with this cleanly. You're left with the paths you see on output

```
.collect()
```

turns this iterator back into a structure defined by the type hints (here, a vector)

The filtering part can be implemented before or after the call to `map()` to turn the entry into a `PathBuf`. If you need to filter based on the element itself and not the `PathBuf`, filter before it. If you can filter based on the `PathBuf`, filter after it.

The use of the `filter()` combinator function is straightforward - you give it a closure, it will apply it to every element. If the return of the closure is `true`, the element is kept. If it is false, the element is dropped.

Here is an example, to only return directories:

```
fn folders(dir: &Path) -> Result<Vec<PathBuf>, io::Error> {
    Ok(fs::read_dir(dir)?
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|r| r.is_ok()) // Get rid of Err variants for Result<DirEntry>
        .map(|r| r.unwrap().path()) // This is safe, since we only have the Ok variants
        .filter(|r| r.is_dir()) // Filter out non-folders
        .collect())
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a line to the effect that `read_dir` returns an `Iterator<Result<DirEntry>>`, which explains the inner `x.map`…

Comment: Why not `.map(|entry| entry.path())`?

Comment: @AlexeyOrlov `read_dir` provides an iterator of results. You cannot use the inner value of a result without handling it.

Comment: @AlexeyOrlov Jmb answered your question, and he's right. I'll edit the answer to add this detail

Comment: I'm still not quite getting it. A map, a filter, whatever - lazy or not, works on a sequence of objects. On what *sequences* the maps work? It looks to me that the inner map works on `Result<DirEntry>`, which is no sequence.

Comment: No. The inner `map` is because the `Iterator` item is a `Result<DirEntry>`. The outer `map` simply maps `Result<DirEntry>` into `Result<PathBuf>`, the inner `map` does the conversion itself.

Comment: As for the rest, `map()` is defined on both `Result` and `Iterator` and **they're different**. The outer `map()` is `Iterator::map()`, which operates on an iterator of elements. The inner map is `Result::map()`

Comment: `Result<DirEntry>` may be seen as a sequence of zero or one element. This is why it has a `map` method.

Comment: @Jmb a `Result` is a one-entry element where the element is typed either as success, or as an error. It contains one element *no matter what*, the type of it is the important part. The actual name for this is a [monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704652/monad-in-plain-english-for-the-oop-programmer-with-no-fp-background)

Comment: @AlexeyOrlov What do you want your filter to do? If you can explain it in plain words, I'll happily write the closure for you to show you

Comment: I want to get just files. Or just directories.

Comment: @AlexeyOrlov https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cbe01cdd391fa243b1522b741c898f36

Comment: The first filter gets rid of elements that aren't `Ok`, the second filter filters whether the inode is a directory

Comment: Will you put it in so many characters? See `UPD:`. If the general idea is right, how am I supposed to access the entry inside my filter's lambda?

Comment: @AlexeyOrlov I added the code that I put in the sandbox on my answer

Comment: @SébastienRenauld and yet you can [iterate over a `Result`](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b785a424a864342760436130086e4d71) which gets you zero or one element. Note that I didn't say that a result **is** a sequence of zero or one element, merely that it **can be seen** as one, and its behaviour is consistent with that view.

Answer (score 2):

you can merge the 2 filter call and keep the result from read_dir. the deref is to be able to check that the path is a dir, without consuming the result

```
fn folders(dir: &Path) -> Result<Vec<PathBuf>, io::Error> {
    fs::read_dir(dir)?
        .map(|r| r.map(|d| d.path()))
        .filter(|r| r.is_ok() && r.as_deref().unwrap().is_dir())
        .collect()
}
```

you can also combine filter and map with filter_map and get rid of the unwrap with ok().and_then()

```
fn folders(dir: &Path) -> Result<Vec<PathBuf>, io::Error> {
    Ok(fs::read_dir(dir)?
        .filter_map(|e| {
            e.ok().and_then(|d| {
                let p = d.path();
                if p.is_dir() {
                    Some(p)
                } else {
                    None
                }
            })
        })
        .collect())
}
```